# C preprocessor include and paths

Tags: c++, header, include, c-preprocessor

Say we have a `.cpp` file `A` including a `.h` file `B` which includes a `.h` file `C`.

```
// File A.cpp
#include "B.h"
...

// File B.h
#include "../../utilityies/C.h"
...
```

If `B` includes `C` using a relative path, is that relative path resolved relatively to the location of `B` or to the location of `A` which is the `.cpp` that `B` is going to be copy-pasted into ?

Comment: A simple test could have sufficed :)

Comment: @bytefire I agree, but you may as well post that to most of the questions on SO.

Comment: @bytefire Aren't programmers supposed to be lazy ? :)

Comment: You are supposed to do basic prior research, though. This is not a "test it for me" site.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: That's why most of the questions on SO have been downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit That would be an interesting statistic to see. On the flip side, now the OP (and people who find this question) knows both the answer to his/her question and _why_ that's the case (at least for gcc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The include path is relative to the file containing it so in your case relative to the location of B.

From the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html):

> GCC looks for headers requested with #include "file" first in the
>   directory containing the current file, then in the directories as
>   specified by -iquote options, then in the same places it would have
>   looked for a header requested with angle brackets. For example, if
>   /usr/include/sys/stat.h contains #include "types.h", GCC looks for
>   types.h first in /usr/include/sys, then in its usual search path.